# Why is the parameter type of a generic function not inferred?

Tags: scala, generics

In Scala 2.11.7, having the following case class and an additional `apply` method:

```
case class FieldValidator[T](key: String, isValid: T => Boolean, 
                             errorMessage: Option[String] = None)

object FieldValidator {
  def apply[T](key: String, isValid: T => Boolean, 
               errorMessage: String): FieldValidator[T] = ???
}
```

when I try to use:

```
FieldValidator[String](key, v => !required || v.nonEmpty, "xxx")
```

I'm getting a "missing parameter type" compilation error pointing at `v`.

When I explicitly specify the type of `v`, it compiles fine, and I can even skip the generic type of the `apply` method, i.e.

```
FieldValidator(key, (v: String) => !required || v.nonEmpty, "xxx")
```

Why isn't the type of `v` inferred when just the generic type of `apply` is provided?

Comment: @RamanMishra I disagree with the proposed duplicate, it's only superficially similar. What's funny about this particular question is that it actually compiles when you remove the `case class FieldValidator`, and leave only `object FieldValidator`. There seems to be some kind of collision between the user-defined `apply` and the synthetic methods.

Comment: Yes I agree @AndreyTyukin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much about generics, it's rather a problem with overloading and default parameters.

First, recall that since `FieldValidator` is a `case`-class, a synthetic factory method

```
def apply(
  key: String,
  isValid: T => Boolean, 
  errorMessage: Option[String] = None
)
```

is automatically added to the companion object `FieldValidator`. This results in `Field` validator having two generic methods with default parameters and same name.

Here is a shorter example that behaves in roughly the same way:

```
def foo[A](f: A => Boolean, x: Int = 0): Unit =  {}
def foo[A](f: A => Boolean, x: String): Unit =  {}

foo[String](_.isEmpty)
```

It results in:

> error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: ) =>
>   x$1.isEmpty)
>
> ```
>  foo[String](_.isEmpty)
>              ^
> ```

I can't pinpoint *what exactly* goes wrong, but essentially, you have confused the compiler with too much ambiguity by throwing three different sorts of polymorphism at it:

- Overloading: you have two methods with name `apply`
- Generics: your methods have a generic type parameter `[A]`
- Default arguments: your `errorMessage` (`x` in my shorter example) can be omitted.

Together, this leaves the compiler with the choice between two equally named methods with unclear types and unclear number of expected type arguments. While flexibility is good, *too much* flexibility is simply *too much*, and the compiler gives up trying to figure out what you wanted, and forces you to specify all types of every single argument explicitly, without relying on inference.

Theoretically, it could have figured it out in this particular case, but this would require much more complex inference algorithms and much more backtracking and trial-and-error (which would slow down the compilation in the general case). You don't want the compiler to spend half a day playing typesystem-sudoku, even if it *theoretically* could figure out a unique solution. Exiting quickly with an error message is a reasonable alternative.

---

**Workaround**

As a simple work-around, consider reordering the arguments in a way that allows the compiler to eliminate ambiguity as fast as possible. For example, splitting the arguments into two argument lists, with two `String`s coming first, would make it unambiguous:

```
case class FieldValidator[T](
  key: String,
  isValid: T => Boolean, 
  errorMessage: Option[String] = None
)

object FieldValidator {
  def apply[T]
    (key: String, errorMessage: String)
    (isValid: T => Boolean)
  : FieldValidator[T] = {
    ???
  }
}

val f = FieldValidator[String]("key", "err"){
  s => s.nonEmpty
}
```